# Process in java and read the output from the file showing error for the first time

Tags: java

I have used **Class Process** to run the external command and accordingly the file is created. Then, I want to read from that file and display the contents of that file.
But for the first time, when there is no file exists (but the file is created during the program) and I run the program showing the errors.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: temp.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at RamSize.main(RamSize.java:13)
```

When I run the program again, it runs successfully.

The program code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class RamSize
{ 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {   
    try 
    {
      String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "(free -h | awk {'print $2'}) > temp.txt"};

      //using the Runtime exec method:      
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.txt"));
       BufferedReader brErr = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

       int count = 0;
       String line;
       while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       {
        count++;
        if(count == 2)
          System.out.println("Ram Size : "+  line);        
       }              
       System.exit(0);       
     }
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    }
}
```

Once the file is created, then after running the program it does not show any error. But I delete the file from the directory and again I run it, it shows the errors. So, it gives errors when file doesn't exists and I run the program.

Comment: At least, please use a `ProcessBuilder`... And then why use `awk` just for that? You can use Java library methods to achieve the same thing at a lesser cost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the child to finish, before accessing the file created in the sub-proces:

```
...
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
...
```

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)

Just found [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime/):

```
public class TestMemory {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int mb = 1024*1024;

        //Getting the runtime reference from system
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        System.out.println("##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####");

        //Print used memory
        System.out.println("Used Memory:"
            + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);

        //Print free memory
        System.out.println("Free Memory:"
            + runtime.freeMemory() / mb);

        //Print total available memory
        System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);

        //Print Maximum available memory
        System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
    }
}
```